# How do I play a .swf file using video.js?

Tags: javascript, video.js

How do I play a `.SWF` file using the `video.js` player?
I've played around with the code below, but I can not get it to work.
When I open the `.swf` file directly (using open with IE), I then I am able to play the `.swf` file that way.

JavaScript:

```
// path to location of swf-file
_V_.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";

// flashvars
_V_.options.flash.flashVars = {
    file: "./ExportSWF/Recording.swf", //file to be played
    autostart: "false",
    provider: "http",
    "http.startparam": "start"
};

// object params
_V_.options.flash.params = {
    allowfullscreen: "true",
    wmode: "transparent",
    allowscriptaccess: "always"
};
```

HTML:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="400" height="300">
```

Answer (score 8):

`video.js` is an *HTML5* video player.
However, the HTML5 `<video>` tag currently only supports a [limited number of formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats):

- WebM
- Ogg Theora Vorbis
- Ogg Opus
- MP4 H.264
- MP3
- WAVE PCM

Some browsers may support a few additional formats, but that's implementation specific.
Please note that Adobe Flash `swf` files are **not** included in that list as they cannot be played with `<video>` tags, only `<embed>` tags.

However, there are a few community created extensions that may accomplish what you're looking for: https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf this is used to make flash as per the creator's readme The light-weight Flash video player that makes Flash work like HTML5 video. This allows player skins, plugins, and other features to work with both HTML5 and Flash

Comment: I am not able to play .swf file with video.js. Can somebody give me the working example of the same.